# excel vba won't execute .bat but manually executing bat works fine

Tags: vba, batch-file, vbscript, execute

Hi I have a perfectly working bat named: start.bat
containing:

```
start C:\Users\*user*\Documents\*path*\hidebat.vbs
```

and once it is manually opened it works perfectly, meaning it opens hidebat.vbs, which opens a .bat minimized which uploads files to my cloud. Hence it's verified.

I've added

```
pause
```

to the start.bat to see what it does and when I tell excel to open the start.bat it will open cmd and display the exact command as required, but it will not execute the hidebat.vbs.

I expect that there is somehow some path constraint or environment constraint when it is run from excel that prevents it to actually reach out of that limited environment.

Within excel I have tried calling the .bat in 3 different ways with:

```
Dim path As String
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
path = path & "\"
Dim MY_FILENAME3 As String
MY_FILENAME3 = path & "start.bat"
```

1.

```
 retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME3, vbNormalFocus)

 ' NOTE THE BATCH FILE WILL RUN, BUT THE CODE WILL CONTINUE TO RUN.
If retVal = 0 Then
    MsgBox "An Error Occured"
    Close #FileNumber
    End
End If
```

2.

```
PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.path
Call Shell(PathCrnt & "start.bat")
```

3.

```
Dim batPath As String: batPath = path

Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /c " & batPath & "start.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

Does anybody have any clue on why it will not execute the .bat file, or what I could do to ensure it will run correctly?

Note. I think it is because it opens the default path, so I'm gonna tell it to "cd" to the actual path where the excel is saved and where the .bat files are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that was it, the path was set to some random/standard/working/current path by command, so I had to add:

```
Print #FileNumber, "cd " & path
```

to the excel macro

so that start.bat looked like:

```
cd *path*
start *path*\hidebat.vbs
```

Hope this helps future me's.